# Aurora replicas never scale in

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have configured aurora read replica auto scaling on my RDS cluster with a target average cpu utilisation of 60%, scale in enabled and a scale in/out period of 300 seconds. The minimum capacity of the cluster is 1 and the maximum is 2.

The replicas seem to scale out as expected, although the auto scaling activity always fails with `Tried to add read replica(s) <ID>. Failed to determine if read replica(s) have been added by rds. Reason: One or more of the created DB instances transitioned to states other than 'available'.` even though the replica works.

However the replicas never get removed. Once auto scaling adds one, it sits there forever, and I suspect this is to do with the fact RDS thinks the replica failed to add... but I have no idea how to fix it. The closest I've found as a cause is table locks but I need to use table locks in my application and it needs to scale during the hours it's used the most.

Comment: Note that your terminology seems reversed. "Scale Out" means *adding* capacity ("out" is used to mean  "becoming more broad"), and "Scale In" means *reducing* capacity ("in" is used to mean "becoming more narrow").

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks michael, I didn't realise. I've corrected it now

Comment: Honestly, this seems like it could be a defect or weakness in RDS -- an unhandled edge case -- rather than a misconfiguration on your part. Based on that, I think the official forum is the place for this question, and it looks like you [posted](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=298543&tstart=0) it there.  You will want to fix the body, here, where you said they "scale in just fine" -- even though the rest of the paragraph is about scaling out.  I made that edit, above.  Feel free to correct it and clarify if that was not your intended meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my fault, I had deleted the cloudwatch alarm which handled the removal of RDS nodes.

AWS Support advised me to delete and re-create the auto scaling policy so the cloudwatch alarms would be recreated and it would scale properly.

The error messages I was seeing were an issue that Amazon was aware of and seem to have since disappeared by themselves.